# Bytes to signed short

Tags: c#, c++

I get two bytes, for example 0xFE and 0x70, it should represent the value of -400. How could I convert those bytes to signed short? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why signed char? That would only be able to contain a single byte, not two. Perhaps you mean `short`? Do you want this in C# or C++? What have you tried?

Comment: 'Is it even possible?' You don't have much faith in the expressive power of computer languages. It can be done in one line of code as Richard shows below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should work in C, C++ and C# (and possible java)

```
 short val;
 val = (byte1 << 8) | byte2;
```

Comment: Thanks, Richard. Maybe you can provide a solution how to convert it back? short to byte1 and byte2?

Comment: byte1 = (val >> 8) & 0xff; byte2 = val & 0xff;

Answer (score 6):

In C/C++ you can use `union`:

```
union Foo {
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(short)];
    short value;
};

. . .

bool isBigEndian()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.value = 0x0102;
    return foo.bytes[0] == 0x01;
}

. . .

Foo foo;

if (isBigEndian()) {
    foo.bytes[0] = 0xFE;
    foo.bytes[1] = 0x70;
}
else {
    foo.bytes[1] = 0xFE;
    foo.bytes[0] = 0x70;
}

bool shouldBeTrue = foo.value == -400;
```

**UPDATE-UPDATE**. This solution is correct for big-endian and little-endian computers. Thanks for πάντα ῥεῖ.

In C# you can use [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66(v=VS.110).aspx) and [BitConverter.ToInt16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16(v=vs.110).aspx). To test endianess you can check [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Take care to mention endianess pitfalls for this solution.

Comment: I get a value of 28926.

Comment: you a little bit wrong. For -400 it need [other order](http://ideone.com/RUESVD)

Ow, you already told about big/little endian.

Comment: @POTEMKINDX I think your the machine at the your link is little-endian. Try enter EF70 in the page http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter, and check **INT16 Big Endian** field.

Comment: I need this in iOS app. But when I enter the FE70 in the page it shows me -400.

Comment: @Roo I've updated my answer to process both big and little-endian architectures.

Answer (score 0):

This works in C#:

```
byte[] arr = { 0xFE, 0x70 };
string hexStr = String.Join("", arr.Select(b => b.ToString("X")));
short res = Convert.ToInt16(hexStr, 16);

Console.WriteLine(res); // -400
```